What is the alternative to the deprecated `cudnnConvolutionForward` function in cuDNN 9.0?
I am currently working on a project that uses cuDNN for convolutional neural networks. However, I've encountered the message:
(https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/latest/api/cudnn-cnn-library.html#id116)
This function has been deprecated in cuDNN 9.0.
when trying to use the cudnnConvolutionForward function. Could someone please advise me on which API I should use as an alternative to cudnnConvolutionForward in newer versions of cuDNN?

Replacement for deprecated cuDNN functions - official NVIDIA migration path? is a duplicate.
